# Skip x axis points on highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to figure out if this can be done with Highcharts. I have 5 different series on my chart and my X axis is made up of Dates. My problem is this, lets say Series 1 has 2 data points 10 and 15 with dates of 5/1/2013 and 5/3/2013. My second Series has Data that is 15 and 20 with dates of 5/1/2013 and 5/4/2013.

What will end up happening is that 5/1/2013 will show up twice and 5/4/2013 wont show up at all.

Now if I remove the duplicate dates, it causes another issue if Series 3 is 5, 10 with 5/3/2013 and 5/4/2013, Instead of the 5 being listed on 5/2/2013 it is showing up on 5/1/2013.

Is there any way around this? or will I have to make different charts for each Series I want listed on there?

Thanks,

Chris

Comment: Recreate issue on jsfiddle, please.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/K7XES/1/ dates are saying invalid for some reason, but it still shows that there are only 2 dates listed instead of 3

Comment: Fixed the date thing..stupid error http://jsfiddle.net/K7XES/2/